# How can I join conditionally based on a value joined to the join?

Tags: mysql, join

I am not sure if this is possible, but I want to get all records back, as well as their attachment, if its type (a definition table) is 'main' (if it has an attachment, but it's type is something else, I want it to be NULL.

```
SELECT r.*
FROM record r
LEFT JOIN attachment d on d.record_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN attachment_type at on d.type_id = at.id
WHERE at.name = "main"
GROUP BY r.id
```

I would do some redesign of the data here, but that's not possible. Could I use a subquery to get the id before doing the join?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your attachment column table looks like (beyond the fact that it has a `type` column), but something like this should be close, meaning (a) it'll return all rows, and (b) the returned attachment value will be null if the type is `main`:

```
SELECT
  r.*,
  CASE WHEN at.name = 'main' THEN d.whatever ELSE NULL END AS attach_thingie
FROM record r
LEFT JOIN attachment d on d.record_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN attachment_type at on d.type_id = at.id
```

And, as @FreshPrinceOfSO mentioned in the comment above, I don't see any need for the `GROUP BY`.

One more thing: based on what I can infer from the query, I don't see any glaring design problems among the three tables. I read it as `record` can have any number of `attachment` and `attachment` has (maybe) a `type`. If that's what your requirements call for you should be OK.

---

**Addendum**: choose a maximum of one attachment per record based on the `attachment.id` column:

```
SELECT r.*, d.whatever
FROM record r
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT attachment.record_id, MAX(attachment.id) AS Max_ID
    FROM attachment
    INNER JOIN attachment_type at ON attachment.type_id = at.id
    WHERE at.name = 'main'
    GROUP BY attachment.record_id
  ) att ON r.id = att.record_id
LEFT JOIN attachment d ON d.id = att.Max_ID
```

Comment: That seems to mostly do the trick.. the reason I had the GROUP BY is because I only want one result per record_id even if it has multiple attachments. Perhaps calling the table record made that not entirely clear.

Comment: In that case the `GROUP BY` should work, though there's no telling which of the attachments will be picked. If you want to pick by specific criteria just let me know - that should be doable but it'll be a bit more involved.

Comment: That was where it was getting tricky.. I want to select the first attachment that has the type of 'main' if one exists. If multiple exist it doesn't matter for this query as long as one is returned

Comment: @EdGibbs Please stop encouraging the incorrect use of `GROUP BY`. The OP needs `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Will do @FreshPrinceOfSO. I'm working with the OP to figure out *which* single record to return rather than the random-ish result from `GROUP BY`, which I have a hard time trusting - it feels like an unintentional side effect of `GROUP BY` that could go away in a future release. `DISTINCT` won't work here because the attachment is part of the desired result.

Comment: @Damon, do you have specific criteria for *which* of the attachments to return, perhaps based on a date value or the PK or something like that?

Comment: I guess I'd go for the one with the higher ID. There shouldn't ever be more than one document of that type.

Comment: That's the spirit! Is the actual column name `attachment.id`?

Comment: @EdGibbs It's not a side effect, it's a disability. However, MySQL calls it an extension. This functionality does not exist in any other platform and thus its use should be discouraged.

Comment: @Damon, I've posted a new query as an addendum to the answer above. It's not tested because I don't have all the relevant column names. It should be close, but if you can't make it work could you post a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) of your tables? With a Fiddle I'm sure we could sort this out quickly.